Parallel vs Serial computing using Python Qutip. Why is serial faster?
I am trying to learn parallel computing using qutip's parallel_map function. I've tried to write a basic and simple code to understand the differences between parallel and serial calculation of parallel_map function.
First the code generates a random N by N matrix, then calculates the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix. I want to perform this for 30 times.
For serial computing, it loops over 30 times. For parallel one, it supposed to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors at the same time.
However, my code says that serial one works faster:

Serial run time: 0.0033600330352783203 seconds
Parallel run time: 0.066878080368041 seconds

Another thing is that after N > 7, parallel one becomes much more slower.
I cannot understand why is this happening. Thanks for your help in advance.
from scipy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np
from qutip.parallel import parallel_map
import time

def eigenvalues_and_vectors(index):
    np.random.seed(int(time.time()) + index)
    N = 8
    matrix = np.random.rand(N, N)
    E, v = LA.eig(matrix)
    return (E , v)

num_iterations = 30

range_num = range(num_iterations)

# Measure serial execution time
start_time_serial = time.time()
# Sequential way
for i in range(num_iterations):
    eigenvalues_and_vectors(i)
end_time_serial = time.time()


# Measure parallel execution time
start_time_parallel = time.time()
# Parallel way
eigs = parallel_map(eigenvalues_and_vectors, range_num, progress_bar=True)
end_time_parallel = time.time()



print(f"Serial   run time: {end_time_serial - start_time_serial} seconds")
print(f"Parallel run time: {end_time_parallel - start_time_parallel} seconds")



There is some small amount of overhead associated with spawning parallel tasks.  This can usually be amortized over much longer computations performed within a task.  However, your tasks are so trivial that this doesn't happen.  Try this again after changing "N=8" to something like "N=8000".

There is also a good chance that the eigensolver is already parallelized over multiple threads (for example on my install it is). Trying to spawn multiple tasks which are each competing for your full CPU will lead to resource contention and excessive context switching, slowing down overall execution.
